# Downloading files stuck android application: worklight

Tags: javascript, android, ibm-mobilefirst

i implemented a application on work-light in which I need to download files from the server, its works well on Iphone5 means files are downloading smoothly without stuck the application flow.however when i run the application on my Samsung galaxy s2 (V 4.1) and start downloading files using for loop my application get stuck till the downloading completed. however its works fine when i have only one file to dowload but when the count is above 3 or 4 application get stuck.

if(networkInfo.networkConnectionType=='WIFI'){

```
                                $(brandClassDis).addClass('ui-disabled'); // Disabling the Brand.
                                $(".lms_loadernew").css("display", "block");
                                var syncProgBar = "#syncProgressBar"+result[0].json.BrandID;
                                var syncProgLabel = "#syncLoadingLabel"+result[0].json.BrandID;
                                $(syncProgBar).progressbar({
                                    value: 0,
                                }).show();
                                $(syncProgLabel).text(parseInt(0, 10)+"%").show();
                                localStorage.setItem("download"+result[0].json.BrandID,0);
                                localStorage.setItem("downloadSucc"+result[0].json.BrandID,0);
                                for(var i=0; i<result.length; i++){
                                    var obj = {VideoID:result[i].json.VideoID,BrandID:result[i].json.BrandID,CourseID:result[i].json.CourseID,LoadingStatus:"0"};
                                    VideosList.add(obj,{push:false});
                                    result[i].json.IsDownload = 2;
                                    Videos.replace(result);

                                            **downloadFolder(result[i],result.length)**

                                }   
                            }
```

function downloadFolder(result,numVideoBrand){

```
try{
    var loaderPer = 0;
    var courseId ="#sync_"+result.json.CourseID.replace(/ /g,'');
    var courseLabelId ="#loadingLabel"+result.json.CourseID.replace(/ /g,'');
    var syncProgBar = "#syncProgressBar"+result.json.BrandID.replace(/ /g,'');
    var syncProgLabel = "#syncLoadingLabel"+result.json.BrandID.replace(/ /g,'');
    var serverLoc = encodeURI(result.json.DownloadName);
    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function(fileSystem) {
        fileSystem.root.getDirectory("LMS_APP", {create: true, exclusive: false}, function(directory){
            var localPath = directory.fullPath+"/"+"Videos"+"/"+zipFileName;
            var ft = new FileTransfer();
            ft.download(serverLoc,localPath, function(entry) {
                entry.file(function(file) {
                    WL.Logger.debug("File size: " + file.size);
                    if(file.size<=854){
                        downloadFail("",result,numVideoBrand);
                        entry.remove(successRemove, failRemove);
                    }else{
                        if(localStorage.getItem("download"+result.json.BrandID) == null || localStorage.getItem("download"+result.json.BrandID) =="" || localStorage.getItem("download"+result.json.BrandID) == undefined){
                            localStorage.setItem("download"+result.json.BrandID,1);
                        }else{
                            localStorage.setItem("download"+result.json.BrandID,(localStorage.getItem("download"+result.json.BrandID)-(-1)));
                        }

                        localStorage.setItem("downloadSucc"+result.json.BrandID,(localStorage.getItem("downloadSucc"+result.json.BrandID)-(-1)));

                        WL.Logger.debug("Folder is:---->"+directory.fullPath+"/"+zipFileName);
                        WL.Logger.debug("download"+localStorage.getItem("download"+result.json.BrandID)+"..."+numVideoBrand+"........"+ localStorage.getItem("downloadSucc"+result.json.BrandID));
                        var loadedVideoPer = (( localStorage.getItem("download"+result.json.BrandID)/numVideoBrand)* 100);
                        $(syncProgBar).progressbar({
                            value: loadedVideoPer,
                        });
                        $(syncProgLabel).text(parseInt(loadedVideoPer, 10)+"%");
                        $(courseId).hide();
                        $(courseLabelId).hide();
                    }
                }, function(error){downloadFail(error,result,numVideoBrand);});

            }, function(error) {

            });
            $(courseId).progressbar({
                value: loaderPer,
            }).show();

            $(courseLabelId).text(parseInt(loaderPer, 10)+"%").show();

            ft.onprogress = function(progressEvent) {

                if (progressEvent.lengthComputable) {
                    loaderPer = ((progressEvent.loaded / progressEvent.total)*100);
                    $(courseId).progressbar({
                        value: loaderPer,
                    });
                    $(courseLabelId).text(parseInt(loaderPer, 10)+"%");
                    //courseLabelId.text(parseInt(loaderPer, 10) + "%" );
                    loadingStatus(result);
                } 
            };  

        },function(error){
            downloadFail(error,result,numVideoBrand);
        });

    }, function(error){
        downloadFail(error,result,numVideoBrand);
    });
}catch(e){

    WL.Logger.debug("exp in downloadFile: "+e);
    //alert("exp "+videoLoader);
}
```

}

Comment: Did you try with other Android devices as well? Is it exclusive to this device or any Android device? Emulator?

Comment: yeah i have tested this on many android device like s2, s3 and htc one x , however issue in all devices. do java script support recursive calling?

Comment: Generally, yes. You say this works in iOS but fails in Android, so that's not the problem exactly... Maybe Android can't handle it well. Is there anything in LogCat before, during or after this happens? Any warnings or errors?

Comment: nops just it block java script as well whole application.

Comment: Hmm, no bright ideas here. See if this question will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15505959/output-delayed-from-cordova-plugin

Comment: were you able to solve this problem?

Comment: yeah i am , i use to download file in queue, coz downloading all file at once cause the application stuck...:)

Comment: Please write the above as an answer to the question.

Answer (score 0):

From the comments, the solution was to:

> download file in queue, coz downloading all file at once cause the
>   application stuck...